# If/else statement not executing correctly with event listener inside; Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, addeventlistener

The goal here is to have a score keeper. Each time you click a button pertaining to a certain player they will have their score increase by one. Once one of the players reach the designated winning score you can not add anymore to the score. My question is why does this code not work, the logic makes sense in my head and I want to understand why it will not give me the alert and why you can keep adding to each score. I have figured out a way to make it work but still believe this should be able to execute correctly. Thank you for helping me out!

```
var p1Button = document.querySelector("#p1");
var p2Button = document.getElementById("p2");
var p1Display = document.getElementById("p1Display");
var p2Display = document.getElementById("p2Display");
var p1Score = 0;
var p2Score = 0;
var winningScore = 5;


if(p1Score !== winningScore && p2Score !== winningScore){
p1Button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  p1Score++;
  p1Display.textContent = p1Score;
  return p1Score;
});
p2Button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  p2Score++;
  p2Display.textContent = p2Score;
  return p2Score;
});
}
else {
  alert("game over");
}
```

Comment: this script will load only once so the if else will also execute only once that's why it's not showing the alert

Comment: you can add an onChange() listener on those score display inside which u can check for their value, if is equals to winning score show the alert.

Comment: *"why does this code not work"* - In what way does it fail?  What are you expecting it to do?  What does it do?  When you debug, how specifically does it fail?  (Or, I guess, why do you *expect* that `if` statement to ever be `false` when you just set those variables to non-equal values right before it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this https://jsfiddle.net/zcuuwsqo/3/

In your code the `if(p1Score !== winningScore && p2Score !== winningScore){` will run only once, that to on the begining of execution, it wont be trigged on every click

you can have something like this

```
function checkScores() {
  if(p1Score === winningScore || p2Score === winningScore){
    alert("game over");
    p1Button.removeEventListener("click", clickListener);
    p2Button.removeEventListener("click", clickListener);
  }
}

function clickListener(e) {
    if(e.target.id === 'p1')
        p1Display.textContent = ++p1Score;
     else
        p2Display.textContent = ++p2Score;

    checkScores();
    return score;
}

p1Button.addEventListener("click", clickListener);
p2Button.addEventListener("click", clickListener);
```

Comment: This answer is incomplete. You need to remove the event listeners, otherwise, when the alert box is closed, the score keeps increasing.

Comment: Yeah @ArmanOzak you are right, code has updated, plz check it